# Integration between local LAN application and website

Tags: php, web, integration

I have a php application running on the local xampp server, the application has data that needs to be synced with a website database. The application and website are in php/mysql...My question is how can i sync them up keeping in mind security issues.

Thnx.

Comment: I'm led to wonder what the relationship is between the local app and the remote app, and whether the syncing you need is purely at a database level. Are they: (1) source-sink apps of a larger app (2) identical apps running in parallel, or (3) two unrelated apps communicating with each other? I could think of different approaches for each of these situations..

Comment: i think it may fall on (3) - coz its a reservation app syncing with the site so that reservations and booking can be done in a much clever and realistic way. Plus the managers would like to access some of the statistics from the app, while they are away....

Answer (score 0):

A clever and quasi secure method would be to use SSL and HTTP auth to post PHP serialized data to the website with some sort of query/post params that the website checks for. Obviously not impenetrable, but it'd avoid the casual exploiter and be relatively simple to implement.

Comment: what about letting my local application access the database hosted on the site

Comment: Not recommended, that would be opening up your database to the public. Sure it's technically feasible, but I wouldn't want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, both applications are relying on MySQL, you can consider using MySQL database replication - set one server as master, second as slave. That way your database on slave server will always be up-to-date.

You can read more about MySQL database replication here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html